# Can not use multiple service in one controller in angular

Tags: angularjs

When I use multiple services in one controller, I got a message : "Undefine" of one service.

I inject service like this:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .controller('MyController', [
        '$scope', 'Service1', 'Service2', 'Service3',
        function( $scope, Service1, Service2, Service3 ) {
          ...
        }
    ]);
```

Can you find this problem?

Comment: Need a little bit more than that do go an. Which service does the message say is undefined? Can you post the exact error message? Can you show how your services are defined?

Comment: In your html you need to reference the file that defines the service.

Comment: The reason that I got an "Undifined" because I forget return the value that I initialized. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .controller('MyController', function( $scope, Service1, Service2, Service3 ) {
          ...
        }
    );
```